# SSIS Substring Extract based on qualifier

Tags: ssis, expression

I've looked through a few different post trying to find a solution for this. I have a column that contains descriptions that follow the following format:

```
String<Numeric>
```

However the column isn't limited to one set of the previous mentioned format it could be something like

```
UNI<01> JPG<84>
JPG<84> UNI<01>
JPG<84>
UNI<01>
```

And other variations without any controlled pattern.

What I am needing to do is extract the number between <> into a separate column in another table based on the string before the <>. So UNI would qualify the following numeric to go to a certain table.column, while JPG would qualify to another table etc. I have seen functions to extract the numeric but not qualifying and only pulling the numeric if it is prefaced with a given qualifier string.

Comment: Could you have `Foo<NN> Bar<NN> Blat<NN>`

Comment: Currently it is only Foo<NN> Bar<NN>, Foo<NN>, or Bar<NN> but I can't guarantee that in the future it couldn't be Foo<NN> Bar<NN> Blat<NN> that's why I would like to handle it by qualifying that after Foo grab what is inside of <>. I've considered trying to handle it in a script versus using the Substring functions but also would prefer to just handle it with standard package tools if possible.

Comment: The problem with this is that you can't have arbitrary column count in SSIS. You'd need to define the upper limit of columns you need to parse out values for.

Comment: So I plan to have multiple flows so lets assume that in any given data flow I'm only looking for Foo, Bar, or Blat and that the other two would be handled in their own data flow. I only want foo as it will be writing to a foo dim table, bar to it's dim table, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the scope limitation mentioned in the question's comments that only one type of token (Foo, Bar, Blat, etc.) needs to be found at a time: you could use an expression in a Derived Column to find the token of interest and then extract the value between the arrows.

For example:

```
FINDSTRING([InputColumn], @[User::SearchToken] + "<", 1) == 0)?
    NULL(DT_WSTR, 1) :
    SUBSTRING([InputColumn], 
        FINDSTRING([InputColumn], @[User::SearchToken] + "<", 1) 
            + LEN(@[User::SearchToken]) + 1, 
        FINDSTRING(
                SUBSTRING([InputColumn], 
                    FINDSTRING([InputColumn], @[User::SearchToken] + "<", 1) 
                        + LEN(@[User::SearchToken]) +  1,
                LEN([InputColumn])
        ), ">", 1) - 1
    )
```

First, the expression checks whether the token specified in `@[User::SearchToken]` is used in the current row. If it is, `SUBSTRING` is used to output the value between the arrows. If not, NULL is returned.

The assumption is made that no token's name will end with text matching the name of another token.  Searching for token *Bar* will match *Bar<123>* and *FooBar<123>*. Accommodating *Bar* and *FooBar* as distinct tokens is possible but the requisite expression will be much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [asynchronous Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx) that outputs a row with type and value columns for each `type<value>` token contained in the input string. Pass the output of this component through a Conditional Split to direct each *type* to the correct destination (e.g. table).

**Pro:** This approach gives you the option of using one data flow to process all tag types simultaneously vs. requiring one data flow per tag type.

**Con:** A Script Component is involved, which it sounds like you'd prefer to avoid.

### Sample Script Component Code

```
private readonly string pattern = @"(?<type>\w+)<(?<value>\d+)>";

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(Row.Data, pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture))
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.Type = match.Groups["type"].Value;
        Output0Buffer.Value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
    }
}
```

Note: Script Component will need an output created with two columns (perhaps named Type and Value) and then have the output's `SynchronousInputID` property set to `None`).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a CTE for a view to handle the data manipulation and then handled the joins and other data pieces in the SSIS package.

```
;WITH RCTE (Status_Code, lft, rgt, idx)
AS (        SELECT  a.Status_code
                                            ,LEFT(a.Description,                        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', a.Description)=0 THEN LEN(a.Description)  ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', a.Description)-1 END) 
                                            ,SUBSTRING(a.Description,         CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', a.Description)=0 THEN LEN(a.Description)  ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', a.Description)-1 END + 1, DATALENGTH(a.Description))
                                            ,0
            FROM   [disp] a WHERE NOT( Description IS  NULL OR Description ='')

            UNION ALL

            SELECT  r.Status_Code
                                            ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', r.rgt) = 0 THEN r.rgt ELSE LEFT(r.rgt, CHARINDEX(' ', r.rgt) - 1) END
                                            ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', r.rgt) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(r.rgt, CHARINDEX(' ', r.rgt) + 1, DATALENGTH(r.rgt)) ELSE '' END
                                            ,idx + 1
            FROM   RCTE r 
            WHERE DATALENGTH(r.rgt) > 0 
)

SELECT  Status_Code
--                             ,lft,rgt                   -- Uncomment to see whats going on 
                            ,SUBSTRING(lft,0, CHARINDEX('<',lft)) AS [Description]
                            ,CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(lft, CHARINDEX('<',lft)+1, LEN(lft)-CHARINDEX('<',lft)-1)) >0
                                              THEN      CAST (SUBSTRING(lft, CHARINDEX('<',lft)+1, LEN(lft)-CHARINDEX('<',lft)-1) AS INT) ELSE NULL END as Value 
FROM RCTE
where lft <> ''
```